# Extension "mysql_fdw" is not supported by Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, rds

I have a AWS PostgreSQL RDS instance. I want to create `mysql_fdw` extension to communicate to MySQL RDS. When I try to create this extension, I am getting the following error

```
ERROR:  Extension "mysql_fdw" is not supported by Amazon RDS
DETAIL:  Installing the extension "mysql_fdw" failed, because it is not on the list of extensions supported by Amazon RDS.
HINT:  Amazon RDS allows users with rds_superuser role to install supported extensions. See: SHOW rds.extensions;*
```

Is there any way to create this extension in AWS RDS?

Answer (score 3):

Available extensions are listed be the below and are specific to Postresql version.

No version currently has mysql_fdw

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_PostgreSQL.Extensions.log_fdw

Per the below, you cannot add your own Extensions to RDS

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111477/amazon-rds-postgresql-adding-new-extensions

Might be specifically because you need MySQL's C client library.

Not going to be able to do this

Would require have super user access to underlying VM which would be a huge risk for AWS

Comment: Thanks for this info.